# Unrecognized option -J-Xmx4G with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have copied a scala project from lightbend academy akka course and imported it in IntelliJ.
When I run command at the project root:

> sbt

I get error:

> Unrecognized option: -J-Xmx4G

But running same command elsewhere, I have no error and all works fine.

What change is needed in the project?

Edit: I removed -J options from .sbtopts, and now it works fine. Not sure why it happened though.

Comment: -J-Xmx - for unix/linux/mac; -Xmx - for Windows.  As always, everything is done on crutches